# angular ng build process taking high cpu on server

Tags: javascript, angular, devops

According to devops the **ng build --prod** command is taking to high cpu usage that why our server costing is increase. I don't know how i optimize this build process, but i have doubt when i run my ng build command on locally and on the server the console output is different.

**prod console.:**

```
⠋ Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)... [2K [1G⠙ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)... [2K [1G⠹ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)... [2K [1G⠸ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)... [2K [1G⠼ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)... [2K [1G⠴ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)... [2K [1G⠦ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)... [2K [1G⠧ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)... [2K [1G⠇ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)... [2K [1G⠏ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)... [2K [1G⠋ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)... [2K [1G⠙ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)... [2K [1G⠹ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)... [2K [1G⠸ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)... [2K [1G⠼ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)... [2K [1G⠴ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)... [2K [1G⠦ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)... [2K [1G⠧ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)... [2K [1G⠇ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)... [2K [1G⠏ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)... [2K [1G⠋ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)... [2K [1G⠙ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)... [2K [1G⠹ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)... [2K [1G⠸ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)... [2K [1G⠼ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)... [2K [1G⠴ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)... [2K [1G⠦ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)... [2K [1G⠧ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)... [2K [1G⠇ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)... [2K [1G⠏ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)... [2K [1G⠋ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)... [2K [1G⠙ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)... [2K [1G⠹ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)... [2K [1G⠸ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...
```

Local console:

```
 Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
```

In both console has difference is, on production the **generating browser application...** this line call many times but on local this is call only single time then bundle process is starting.

where is the gap in ng build command on local env and server env

Answer (score 2):

The multiple lines in the server output are just due to the fact that the server log doesn't know how to deal with the animated progress character that is displayed in the console.

For the server build, just disable the progress reporting:

```
ng build --no-progress --prod
```

Comment: thanks for answer robby, pls tell me one more thing is it cause to increase high cpu on server?

Comment: It probably causes some additional overhead, but most likely nothing major. The Angular build process is pretty CPU-intensive... Maybe build less frequently?

Comment: can you please suggest me some point to reduce build command load and how we reduce our server cost?